# Using LZ4 Compression in Java for multiple files

Tags: java, lz4

I'm trying to compress multiple files into a single archive but with my current code, it only compresses it into a single blob inside the zip. Does anyone know how to segment the files with LZ4?

```
public void zipFile(File[] fileToZip, String outputFileName, boolean activeZip)
{
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName), true);
            LZ4FrameOutputStream lz4fos = new LZ4FrameOutputStream(fos);)
    {
        for (File a : fileToZip)
        {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(a))
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSizeZip];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(buf)) > 0)
                {
                    lz4fos.write(buf, 0, length);                                             
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOG.error("Zipping file failed ", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LZ4` algorithm is close with `LZMA`. In case you can use `LZMA` then you can create `zip` archive with `LZMA` compression.

```
List<Path> files = Collections.emptyList();
Path zip = Paths.get("lzma.zip");

ZipEntrySettings entrySettings = ZipEntrySettings.builder()
                                                 .compression(Compression.LZMA, CompressionLevel.NORMAL)
                                                 .lzmaEosMarker(true).build();
ZipSettings settings = ZipSettings.builder().entrySettingsProvider(fileName -> entrySettings).build();

ZipIt.zip(zip)
     .settings(settings)
     .add(files);
```

See details in [zip4jvm](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm)

Answer (score 0):

LZ4 compresses a stream of bytes.  You would need to archive your multiple files into a single archive such as a Tar Archive, then feed it into the LZ4 compressor.

I created a Java library that does this for you https://github.com/spoorn/tar-lz4-java.

If you want to implement it yourself, here's a technical doc that includes details on how to LZ4 compress a directory using TarArchive from Apache Commons and lz4-java: https://github.com/spoorn/tar-lz4-java/blob/main/SUMMARY.md#lz4

Comment: This tar-lz4-java is good, unfortunately it is not in maven repo.